# Finding coefficients of a polynomial limit with zero denominator?

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

Set n as a natural number and suppose that P(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + ...  + a<sub>p</sub>x<sup>p</sup> and Q(x) = b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>x +  ...  + b<sub>q</sub>x<sup>q</sup> are
polynomials of order p and q, respectively.

Such that
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (P(x)-Q(x))/x^n = 0$

Prove that a<sub>j</sub> = b<sub>j</sub> for all j = 0 ... n

I've tried using taylor series or l'hopitals rule but just can't make it work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** Let $R(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + \ldots + c_r x^r$ and assume that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^n} = 0$$

Then $c_j = 0$ for $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n$.

**Proof.** We do strong induction on $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n$: let $0 \leqslant j \leqslant n$ and suppose that for $i < j$ we have that $c_i = 0$. We're going to show that $c_j = 0$.

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^j} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^n} \cdot x^{n-j} = 0$$

because $\frac{R(x)}{x^n} \to0$ and $x^{n-j}$ either tends to zero (if $j < n$) or is constantly equal to $1$ (if $j = n$).

On the other hand, since $c_i = 0$ for $i < j$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{R(x)}{x^j} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{c_j x^j + c_{j+1} x^{j+1} + \ldots + c_r x^r}{x^j} = \lim_{x \to 0} c_j + c_{j+1} x + \ldots + c_r x^{r-j} = c_j,$$

hence $c_j = 0$. So the proof is complete. $\square$

Now to answer your question it suffices to take $R(x) = P(x) - Q(x)$ in the lemma above.

Comment: Nice and simple. +1

Comment: Thank you so much!!